# Why is my code sending the same message to an MSMQ when I'm not expecting it to?

Tags: c#, msmq, send

I'm writing code for an MSMQ client which is used to communicate with an MSMQ server. My sending method will repeatedly send the same message thousand of times with a longer message, which is not expected. With a short message this issue doesn't occur. The receive and send queue are both private queues.

What could be causing this?

I've enabled the MSMQ journal to monitor how many duplicated messages are created.

The sending function:

```
private void Send(string content, string queuePath, int timeToBeReceived)
{
    // check if queue exist
    if (sendQueue == null)
    {
        // remote private queue
        if (queuePath.Contains("FormatName"))
        {
            sendQueue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
        }
        else
        {
            // private queue path
            if (MessageQueue.Exists(queuePath))
            {
                sendQueue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
            }
            else
            {
                sendQueue = MessageQueue.Create(queuePath);
                // Set permissions
                sendQueue.SetPermissions("Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlEntryType.Allow);
            }
        }
    }

    // create message
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter((new Type[] { typeof(string) }));

    try
    {
    // validation
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(content);
        xml = null;

        msg.BodyStream = new MemoryStream();
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        msg.BodyStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        if (timeToBeReceived > 0)
        {
            msg.TimeToBeReceived = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeToBeReceived);
        }
        sendQueue.Send(msg);
        Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        msg.Dispose();
    }
    catch (XmlException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Wrong XML Format Detected!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        return;
    }
}
```

Where call this function from the MainViewModule, the TimeToBeReceived is 0 as default

```
private RelayCommand _sendCommand;

public RelayCommand SendCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _sendCommand
            ?? (_sendCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () =>
            {
                Send(SendText, Properties.Settings.Default.MSMQSendPath, Properties.Settings.Default.TimeToBeReceived);
                SendText = string.Empty;
            }));
    }
}
```

The message body:

```
<result>
<job bsn="000789364" barcode="LJS@000789364@004@IP@LPSTEST@.@.@20190610103346@1@0@.@C519 IP LHD@2.6286@755055@151xx1x1xx1611x1xxx32112111x1x21xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@*000789364*=" jobtype="C519 EB LHD" overallresult="pass"></job>
<tester name="LHD" lane="EB Line 6" version="KSK"></tester>
    <tests performed="2019-01-09 10:31:27" cycletime="187" faultmessage="any useful text">
    <test name="JX6T91A000LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A002LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A003LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A102LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A107LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A111LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A112LBB" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A209LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A303LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A401LGD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A641LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A680LBD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A681LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A682LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A790LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A792LCC" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A793LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91A811LAD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91B111LEC" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91B302LDD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
    <test name="JX6T91B830LCD" result="pass" value="module" status="1"></test>
</tests>
```

I am still working on this issue and found more information. My code is sending the correct message once and then the repeating message comes.
[image: Correct and wrong messages in the Journals]

For the repeating messages, it has no sender user and SID information. The Source computer GUID and name is also different.
[image: Correct and duplicated messages]

The correct journal message properties queue info is in following pattern: **DIRECT=OS:PCName\privates$\queuename.**

The error message's queue Format name is:

**DIRECT=TCP:IPADDRESS\private$\queuename**
[image: Correct message queue name]

What could be the root cause? The issue message size is 2102.

Comment: I would guess that it times out with the longer message every time and tries again. Have you tried longer values for `timeToBeReceived`?

Comment: Hi spodger, thanks for your suggestion, i'm using the default TimeToBeReceived value: infiniteTimeout. Or do you have an idea about catch the sending times out event？

Comment: No sorry - just a poor guess at what a `timeToBeReceived` value of 0 meant.

Comment: Could it be retrying the message due to an uncaught exception?

Comment: Hi Farmer, i will modify the try catch pattern. But the strange thing is the MSMQ server did receive the repeating messages.